# Changing the fill of SVG elements inside canvas?

Tags: html, dom, canvas, svg

Is there a good way to draw external SVG files into an HTML5  tag, then change the fill colour of elements within the SVG file on the fly via Javascript?

***What I've done so far:**

1. Made a new Image object
2. Set it's src to the .svg file in question
3. Gave it an onload function that draws it to the  via ctx.drawImage()

Comment: Yes, which bit are you stuck on though? Adding the data or changing the fill? Show us what you've done so far.

Comment: Okay, edited OP to show how far I've got.

Comment: Image objects are not editable for security/privacy reasons so you're not going to be able to do things this way. You could embed the svg inline instead for instance.

Comment: The reason I need to do it inside a <canvas> is so that they can be dynamically moved and transformed. In this instance the .svg files are customizable sprites that are in a game. Originally it was done in Flash, however it's time to get ios support.

Comment: So use css transforms directly on the inline SVG. Your current approach is doomed.

Comment: Hmm okay I'll look into it. It just seems stupid that you can draw .svg files onto a <canvas> but then not be able to access there inner elements. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Once you've drawn anything onto `canvas` there's no 'inner elements', there's just pixels.  If you want 'inner elements' keep things as SVG.

Comment: Yeah that's why I'm hoping there's something similar to the Image object but for SVG's, so you could make an instance of the .svg, alter it's inner elements, then draw it onto the canvas. Does this exist?